# How do you clear a polygon shaped region in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've used the clearRect function, but didn't see an equivalent for polygons. I naively tried:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'transparent';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

But that just draws a transparent region, and doesn't have an effect on what's already there. Is there a way to clear polygon regions inside of the canvas element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) with the operation set to `'destination-out'` for this:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 90);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Example:

[image]

Try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sykvr/)

Comment: Thanks Jonas! Note to self: for this to work as desired you want an opaque fill color (no alpha transparency).

Comment: Thanks @Benjie, your comment complete the answer, I was looking for it a long time ago.

Comment: works great - link to [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) has moved though

Comment: I realize that this is a pretty old answer, but the jsFiddle no longer works. Perhaps something changed with the canvas specs?